# How to format a disk in ext3 file system with a Block size greater than 4096

Tags: formatting, ext3

I want to format a disk in ext3 file system with the  block size as 4096. Is there any possibility to do so? What if we do not write Inode Bitmap while formatting?

Comment: Why do you want a block size > 4KiB?

Answer (score 0):

ext2/3/4 do not support disk block sizes greater than the page size. On x86-32 and x86-64, the page size is 4K, so that's the largest block size you can use. (OTOH, if you can dig up a DEC Alpha machine, I hear those had 8K pages.)

From your comment, you want to speed up mkfs. There are a couple of approaches you could take:

1. If you don't need all the inodes (remember, adding more will require reformatting), you can decrease the number of inodes. You can use the `-i` or `-N` options to do that. Or use one of the other types (e.g., `-T largefile`).
2. You could use ext4 instead. ext4 can leave block groups uninitialized until they're needed (`-O uninit_bg -E lazy_itable_init`, which are usually the default). Also has the advantage of greatly speeding up fsck.

If you really want to reduce the number of block groups (which you shouldn't), there is a `-g` option for that.

Comment: Right now I am using largefile4 option to reduce number of inodes per block group. So it helps me to reduce formatting time a quite but it is not enough for me. Still it takes time(around 7-8 minutes for 2TB HDD) to write bitmaps i.e, block bitmap and inode bitmap which is quite a long. I thought only the way to reduce the time is to reduce number of block groups which is not possible as commented before. So is there any possibility if I do not write bitmaps in the disk?


As I am using a linux version which does not have ext4 file system support, I am not able to use it.

Comment: @ParshvShah I don't see your comment about not being able to change the number of groups. (Also, you can use `-i`/`-N` to get even fewer inodes than largefile4...) But let's go back a step here, what's the problem you're trying to solve? I mean, for "normal" use, you hardly ever run mkfs, so taking 10 minutes isn't a huge deal. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually 10 minutes are OK for me but I thought if is there any possibility to reduce time then obviously it would be better that is why I put a comment. But heartily thanks a lot for suggestions. It worked for me. At least I am able to reduce a time by 50%.